# Show last appearance of element in list

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to show the last appearance of an element from a given list. For example:     For the list '(1 1 2 1 3 3 4 3 5 6), the result will be '(2 1 4 3 5 6)
    This is the code I have:

```
  (define (func L res)
     (if (not (null? L))
         (foldl (lambda (e) 
                    (if (not (member e (cdr L))) 
                        (cons e (remove-duplicates-right (cdr L)))
                        (remove-duplicates-right (cdr L))))
                res L)
         res))


  (define (show-last-app L)
      (func L '()))
```

The next error occurs: "foldl: given procedure does not accept 2 arguments"

This is how I  solved it only with recursion but I want to use only foldl or filter and don't use functions with side effects:

```
(define (show-last-app L)
  (cond
    ((null? L)
      '())
    ((not (member (car L) (cdr L)))
      (append (list (car L)) (show-last-app (cdr L))))
    (else (show-last-app (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: Your second solution has not side-effects, it is purely functional! It could be simplified a little bit by using `cons` instead of `append`.

Comment: `foldl` receives a function that in turn receives two arguments: an element to process, and the partial result. In your case the lambda function only accepts the element.

Comment: BTW, there's a built-in procedure in Racket that does exactly the same, it's called `delete-duplicates`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how folds work in Scheme. This is closer to what you were aiming for:

```
(define (show-last-app L)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (if (not (member e acc))
               (cons e acc)
               acc))
         '()
         L))
```

If you really, really have to use `foldl`:

```
(define (show-last-app L)
  (foldl (lambda (e acc)
           (if (not (member e acc))
               (cons e acc)
               acc))
         '()
         (reverse L)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(show-last-app '(1 2 4 1 5 3 1 6 2))
=>  (4 5 3 1 6 2)
```

Comment: I don't have to use foldl, any fold was good. I made first appearance with foldl just like you did with the foldr for the second appearance but I didn't think foldr would work because I was imagining that will show the first appearance of the elements from the reversed list, meaning '(2 6 1 3 5 4) was the result I thought of for your example when I wanted to use foldr.